# Password for Facebook Login with Parse in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using PFUser to save registration details of users in Parse including password.

But, When I use Facebook SDK to login, how handle no password case ? Because, we don't get a password from Facebook SDK and we don't need to have one for Single Sign On Login with Facebook. But, PFUser must expecting the password to store and I can't fill it with empty string. Because, many people can try with Email and Empty password which can login the user.

NOTE : I am not using the PFFacebookUtils class of Parse and I don't want to use it even.

Could someone help me by explaining the solution for it ?

Comment: As is see it, have a couple of options. (1) Ask the user for a password when the account is created. Pitch it to them in a way that says they can also use the password for logging on in the future. Or (2) create a long random password. The user can always request a password reset via parse in the future if they want to use it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think the 2nd option fits to my application. :)

Comment: I have another question. how do we implement it actually ? 
I mean, when first sign in with facebook, we just check whether email exists or not and if exists, we just make user to login or if doesn't exist, we store the user info in our database and make user to login. is it correct? or Do we have any other better way to do it ? I am not using any sessions in my app for now. I am using DeviceID as my session parameter to authenticate the device.

Answer (score 1):

When you authenticate a Facebook user with Parse, it creates an Auth token that Facebook uses. The AuthData can be found in the "authData" column in your _User class.

I'm doing the same thing in my app and it works nicely.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, I am not authenticating with parse. I am just authenticating my app and getting information from Facebook and storing the details on Parse database.

Comment: @SaiJithendra you have to authenticate with parse if u want to get it working as facebook SDK don't return passwords.

Comment: I don't need a password. But, I just want user to login using a Facebook SDK and store their information in Parse. I need Single Sign On feature for it. I am really confusing about all these stuff :(

Comment: If you want single sign on, I'm not quite sure you won't just authenticate with Facebook and store that session in Parse. Sessions created using parse and Facebook are valid for 2 years. It seems you're making this a lot more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: I understood and I also have a Google+ sign in which Parse doesn't support with their API as of now. How to handle that ? Do you have any example to clear my confusion? or Could you help me with steps how to make both Facebook and Google+ Login work better with Parse ?